# Aggregate in R Statisitcs

Tags: r, aggregate-functions, aggregate, random-forest

please help me to solve two simple problems in R Statistics. I have to make a dynamic model for the budget forecast. My data looks like:

Date Partner Costs

01.01. eBay 500

etc.

My problems are:

1. How can i make several columns using aggregate? The result should contain the following columns:

Date Partner Cost Forecast Should_Be

31.01 eBay 100 3100 4000

31.01 yahoo ...

etc.

I aggregate data per different Partners like this: `aggregate(data$Costs, by = list(Partner = data$Partner), FUN = sum)`

My result is:

Partner    x

1 ebay 39
...

Furthermore:

- how can i rename this "x" above?

THE SECOND PROBLEM is:

1. I would like to compare the sum of cost per Partner per Day, and if there is a big difference (70%) then the model should take this value and multiply by the rest of the days of a month. Is it a function? For more understanding: Forecast = (costs/numberofdays_gone * numberofday_left) + costs

Basically I take the mean BUT it is often the case that on 01.01. cost per ebay = 100
then on the 02.01. ebay = 2000, so it makes no sense to make the mean on the 20th of a month as the newest information counts.

So, how can i build a function (or smth else) that makes the following:

Automatically (!!!!!) takes a name of a partner in a column `=>` calculates the sum of cost of the 01.01. till the current date `=>` begins to compare the days like this: 02.01 with the 01.01, if there is no 70% difference in costs, takes the next date: 03.01 with the 02.01, etc. If there is a difference then takes THAT date and the formula will look like this:

Forecast = (cost of THAT date * numberofdays_left) + costs

`HOWEVER`better would be if the model sees that

for example:

cost of 10.01 = 500

cost of 11.01 = 2000 (70% of more percent)

cost of 12.01 = 2100 (less than 70%)

and the model takes LAST two - three days and calculates the mean! And the formula would like:
FORECAST = (mean of cost of LAST days * numberofdays_left) + cost

The main difficulty is that the model hast to do it PER PARTNER, and I have a client with like 12 Partners. Is that a big deal for R?

For your help I will be very thankfull! 
I solved the problem with timing - if you want to see let me know!

Answer (score 0):

For the first part use a formula in your aggregate call

Assuming you want to aggregate Cost, Forecast, Should_Be for Each Partner

```
aggregate(cbind(Costs,Forecast,Should_Be) ~ Partner, FUN = sum, data= data)
```

Assuming you want to aggregate Cost, Forecast, Should_Be for Each Partner and Date

```
aggregate(cbind(Costs,Forecast,Should_Be) ~ Partner + Date, FUN = sum, data= data)
```

The column headings will be the name of the variables

Comment: Wow! Many thanks for your answer!!!!! I am so happy to hear that!!!! Thank you very much!!!!!! it works!!! now i have to build the second part, but I have no clue how to do that. I have never built a loop (a while) in R. at least that version works! Thank you! I am sorry, i cannot vote for you, i have no reputation :)